# Преобразование пользовательских типов к системным типам,а также double к сhar*?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Как выполнит преобразование пользовательских типов к системным типам,а также double к сhar*?

Comment: double к `char*` - в смысле преобразовать число в строку или число в массив 8 байт, что бы сохранить/передать?

Comment: Что есть системные типы? И как вы видите приведение 128 байт к указателю, например?

Comment: Ну, всегда есть приведение в стиле С - `(char*)dbl`, но здесь надо отдавать отчет, *что* вы делаете и *зачем*.

Comment: @KoVadim,да число в строку

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов,системные типы,я имею ввиду int,double,char *

Comment: число в строку  - `std::to_string()`. Если очень сильно нужно char* - тогда c_str()

Comment: у меня есть переменная моего класса и мне нужно ее привести к типу сhar *

Comment: @Nikita это не системные типы, а типы языка. Системные типы это всякие HANDLE, всякие WIN32_FIND_DATA и т.п, которые имеют к системе отношение. Остается вопрос: как приводить 128 байт к указателю?

Comment: char* или может все таки string?

Comment: Зачем, в таком случае, объявлять пользовательский тип? По-моему, любой класс можно раздрюкать на встроенные типы и, тем самым, убить ООП.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы преобразование пользовательского типа `C` в какой-либо из стандартных типов было возможным, нужно реализовать оператор преобразования в вашем типе. Например, для преобразования в `int`:

```
struct C {
    operator int() const { return 42; }
};
```

Теперь в тех контекстах, где будет требоваться целое число можно будет использовать объект типа `C`:

```
C c;
std::cout << c << "\n"; // Выведет 42

int i = 1 + c;
std::cout << i << "\n"; // Выведет 43
```

Если неявное преобразование нужно запретить, стоит добавить ключевое слово `explicit`:

```
explicit operator int() const { return 42; }
```

Теперь нужно будет явно писать `static_cast<int>`, чтобы вызвался соответствующий оператор преобразования. Аналогично можно сделать и для целевого типа в виде указателя, например, `char*`:

```
operator const char*() const { return "hello"; }
```

Преобразование встроенных типов друг в друга регламентируется правилами языка, в частных случаях оно может быть довольно бессмысленным. Рекомендую в этом плане ознакомиться с такими операторами как `reinterpet_cast` и `static_cast`.